# How to build an array of objects and then convert the whole array to an string

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have an array that looks like:

```
array = [{...},{...},{...},...];
```

and I only want to convert the array into a simple string like this:

```
String stringArray = "[{...},{...},{...},...]";
```

How can I easily do that?

Comment: If you want array to *look* like string, you can make a screenshot of array and add quotes in some graphic editor like Photoshop. If that is not an option, you should provide some real code instead of pseudo-code

Comment: You could use a `StringBuilder` and append to it while looping over the array.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy MSPaint would be a much more appropriate suggestion, but in any case it would be easiest for OP to paste the screenshot into Word, print it, and find a Sharpie. Given an adequate supply of Wite-Out, the Sharpie could be applied directly to the screen of course. OP, if you could clarify your requirements and whether it's your own computer or a loaner, I could give you more specific advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(",", array.Select(i => "{" + i.ToString() + "}")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to convert a list of object to a JSON array of objects. If that so, then use `NewtonSoft.JSON` and serialize your `List<obj>` to a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

```
string stringArray = "[";
foreach(var item in array)
    stringArray = "{" + item.ToString() + "},";
stringArray += "]"
```